# Posting JSON string to server using HTTP POST

Tags: javascript, php, json

I've been trying to send the result of two forms to a server that reads an JSON output using HTTP POST. Problem is I'm not sure how to see the error messages that I'm supposed to get back.

The function is really simple. There are a two part form, where first you choose what a product that has a few things following, like two prices and quantity. You click next and on the next page you get a personal information form where you can type in your info. When you then click "send" I've been trying to send this information.

This is the code I've been using.

```
function handleCustomSubmission() {
    var url= "http://myserver.com/adminwebservice.dll/SaveOrder";
    var form1  = $('#data-form1').html();
    var form2 = $('<form action="'+url+'" target="data_iframe" method="post" style="display:none;" id="data_form2">'+form1+'</form>');
    var iframe = $('<iframe />').attr('id','data_iframe');
    $('body').append(iframe);
    $('body').append(form2);
    $("#data_form2").submit().remove();
}
```

The JSON format should be something like this:

```
{
    Phone: "123456789",
    Name: "Test Name",
    adress: "105 Street",
    postno: "95202",
    place: "Santa barbara",
    epost: "test@email.com",
    produkter: 
        [
            {
                id:"AB123",
                Name: "Product 1",
                Quantity: "1",
                Price1: "200",
                Price2: "1300"
            },
            {
                id:"CD456",
                Name: "Product 2",
                Quantity: "1",
                Price1: "10",
                Price2: "800"
            }
        ]
}
```

The form itself is pretty standard stuff:

```
<form name="product-enquiry" action="" method="post" id="data-form1">

<label>Name</label>

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name'];?>">
<?php if(isset($name)) { ?> 
    <?php echo $name ?> 
<?php } ?>
```

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated!

Comment: this doesn't make sense "reads an JSON output" also post doesn't magically submit JSON, you can do it with jQuery $.post, or if it's an external sever you can post to your page convert to json and CURL to the server

Comment: Also if you truly POST JSON to the server using proper CONtent Type headers (application/json), you would not even use $_POST at all. You would need to read POST data from PHP raw input.